# SQLAlchemy Many-to-Many relationship Constraining by at Least One

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship in sqlalchemy, lets say its `Clubs` and `Members`.

A `Club` **can have one or many members, but it cannot have none**.
A `Member` **can be a part of none, one or many clubs**.

So this is asymmetric in terms of configuration, and I suspect my symmetric code below will not by default constrain to this.

```
ass_table = Table('association', db.Model.metadata,
    Column('member_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('member.id')),
    Column('club_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('club.id'))
)

class Member(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'member'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    clubs = db.relationship('Club', secondary=ass_table, back_populates='members')

class Club(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'club'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    members = db.relationship('Member', secondary=ass_table, back_populates='clubs')
```

Is there a simple extension that I am missing that ensures integrity as required?

Comment: So the member behavior that you want is the default. Perhaps a `remove_member` method on your `Club` or `leave_club` method on your `User` will allow you to enforce removal of clubs with no members. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/740630/6560549

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Postgres in production. Basic dev and testing in SQlite but doesn'y necesaarily have to be